# Split rectangle into random polygons

Tags: geometry, polygon

I have a rectangle. I want to split it into polygons, which will not overlap and without leaving gaps. I want big ones end smaller ones, non-convex ones too, but all with shape similar to circle. Something like this:
[image: example]
Has anyone any idea or help to solve this problem?

Comment: How about a [Voronoi Diagram](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/882739/Simple-approach-to-Voronoi-diagrams)

Comment: Your polygons don't look very random: they have all roughly the same surface area, and the ratio `area/perimeter` is very tame (does not vary wildly) - Can you please clarify the constraints with a better description, and more details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first generate Voronoi diagram and then add a little modify to introduce some concave ones

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).